# what should be the input and output forom of variables for float object detection model

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api, kotlin-android-extensions, mobilenet

https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/mobilenet_ssd_tflite_v1.zip

I am making an android object detection app with gpu delegate support.
The above link is for tensorflow lite object detection float model. 
There is no documentation available for this. I want to know the input and output form of the variables for this tflite models so that i can feed it to the interpreter for gpu delegation.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use colaboratory. So I use below code to determine inputs and outputs:

```
import tensorflow as tf
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter('mobilenet_ssd.tflite')
print(interpreter.get_input_details())
print(interpreter.get_output_details())
```

So unzip the folder, find the file and load it with above code. I did that with above code and the result was:

[{'name': 'Preprocessor/sub', 'index': 165, 'shape': array([  1, 300, 300,   3], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([  1, 300, 300,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': , 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

[{'name': 'concat', 'index': 172, 'shape': array([   1, 1917,    4], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([   1, 1917,    4], dtype=int32), 'dtype': , 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'concat_1', 'index': 173, 'shape': array([   1, 1917,   91], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([   1, 1917,   91], dtype=int32), 'dtype': , 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

Also inside android you can do:

```
// Initialize interpreter
@Throws(IOException::class)
private suspend fun initializeInterpreter(app: Application) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // Load the TF Lite model from asset folder and initialize TF Lite Interpreter without NNAPI enabled.
    val assetManager = app.assets
    val model = loadModelFile(assetManager, "mobilenet_ssd.tflite")
    val options = Interpreter.Options()
    options.setUseNNAPI(false)
    interpreter = Interpreter(model, options)
    // Reads type and shape of input and output tensors, respectively.
    val imageTensorIndex = 0
    val inputShape: IntArray =
        interpreter.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).shape() // {1, length}
    Log.e("INPUT_TENSOR_WHOLE", Arrays.toString(inputShape))
    val imageDataType: DataType =
        interpreter.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).dataType()
    Log.e("INPUT_DATA_TYPE", imageDataType.toString())

    //modelInputSize indicates how many bytes of memory we should allocate to store the input for our TensorFlow Lite model.
    //FLOAT_TYPE_SIZE indicates how many bytes our input data type will require. We use float32, so it is 4 bytes.
    //PIXEL_SIZE indicates how many color channels there are in each pixel. Our input image is a colored image, so we have 3 color channel.
    inputImageWidth = inputShape[1]
    inputImageHeight = inputShape[2]
    modelInputSize = FLOAT_TYPE_SIZE * inputImageWidth *
            inputImageHeight * PIXEL_SIZE

    val probabilityTensorIndex = 0
    outputShape =
        interpreter.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).shape()// {1, NUM_CLASSES}
    Log.e("OUTPUT_TENSOR_SHAPE", outputShape.contentToString())
    val probabilityDataType: DataType =
        interpreter.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).dataType()
    Log.e("OUTPUT_DATA_TYPE", probabilityDataType.toString())
    isInitialized = true
    Log.e(TAG, "Initialized TFLite interpreter.")


    // Inputs outputs
    /*val inputTensorModel: Int = interpreter.getInputIndex("input_1")
    Log.e("INPUT_TENSOR", inputTensorModel.toString())*/

}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun loadModelFile(assetManager: AssetManager, filename: String): MappedByteBuffer {
    val fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(filename)
    val inputStream = FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)
    val fileChannel = inputStream.channel
    val startOffset = fileDescriptor.startOffset
    val declaredLength = fileDescriptor.declaredLength
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength)
}
```

If you need any help tag me.

Comment: Hey its not working. Do you know any object detection tflite float models which gives four outputs (bounding box, label prediction, confidence, number of detections)? @Farmaker

Comment: I printed with above code the results. Check edited answer with the code I provided.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would appreciate if you could answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62373305/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-the-screen-using-coordinates-with-texture-view