# How to draw a rectangle on the screen using coordinates with texture view?

Tags: android, kotlin, textureview

I am previewing camera feed to texture view using cameraX. How to draw a rectangle on the screen using coordinates that i have? I don't want a complex function. I simply want to draw a rectangle.
I am using kotlin and android studio 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for an ImageView overlapping on top of the Textureview at the same xml. This imageview will load a transparent bitmap that will have only the rectangle drawn. If you have the coordinates u have to do:

```
val myRectPaint = Paint()
myRectPaint.strokeWidth = 5F
myRectPaint.color = Color.RED
myRectPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE

// Create a Canvas object for drawing on the original bitmap provided
val tempBitmap =
    Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap!!.width, bitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val tempCanvas = Canvas(tempBitmap)
tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0F, 0F, null)

tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(
            RectF(x1.toFloat(), y1.toFloat(), x2.toFloat(), y2.toFloat()),
            2f,
            2f,
            myRectPaint
        )

// Use this to widen picture on top or bottom
    val croppedFaceBitmap =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBitmap, x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

In any case you can also follow [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android) from tensorflow github where round boxes are drawn when object is detected.

Hope I helped

Comment: Sundar, in that case follow the example of the official tensorflow project of the object detection...Build it to see how rectangles are drawn...and if it suit your case follow it.

Comment: I've been tryinng to resolve this for 6 hours now but nothing seems to be working. would you take a look at my project if I share the link with you.

Comment: Yes sure share it!

Comment: I am working on it. I am unable to build the project. BUT I see on classifier file on lines 186-200 that u are not using the outputMap that comes out of the interpreter inference anywhere. Why??

Comment: Actually i don't need that output map, I am directly using its inner data variable in the for loop below interpreter inference line. But I am able to build the project, there was no error on my side

Comment: Check the output of the interpreter to pass it inside recognitions arraylist as long as I try to build it

Comment: or maybe that's where the error lies, i am not able to figure that out. I copied that part of the code from somewhere else.

Comment: if you read it u will see that you do not pass the results to recognitions arraylist but the first empty arrays

Comment: while building, make sure that tensorflow-lite and gpu version is set to 2.2.0

Comment: Things are getting saved to the recognitions, I have checked it by printing it to the log

Comment: Sundar..project does not compile. Clean project and send it again please

Comment: Hey, Please don't bother. I resolved the issue. The problem was with mapping output coordinates to the screen. I really appreciate your help and concern. Will bother you again if get stuck at some point. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Happy coding

Comment: @Sundar I saw why it didnt show boxes. It was because imageview was hidden back of Textureview. Mine preview of the bitmap was roteted also!! My suggestion is to go with the state of the art but more complex [tensorflow lite project](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android) because it has 2 custom views that are overlapping...and seemless drawing on the screen

Comment: Can you  help me get the label file for a tensorflow lite model?  http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.tar.gz  Pls try to do it at your earliest convenience. I am approaching deadline.

Comment: Really sorry Sundar...I have started a project yesterday and I don't have time

Comment: oh, no problem.

Comment: Hey @user11375418 , how were you able to map the coordinates to screen? Were to able to achieve it ?