# Fixing incorrect boundingBox coordinates?

Tags: java, graphics, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

I'm working on an object detection application for Android (in Java) using Google ML and CameraX. I'm also using a Tensorflow model, which can be found [here](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/mobilenet_v1_0.75_192_quantized/1/metadata/1). My issue is that the coordinates of my boundingBox are so slightly misaligned, as demonstrated in the following image. Please ignore the fact that it's being detected as a spatula, my issue currently is focused on capturing the image within the graphic displayed on the screen.

[image]

This is the following class that was used to draw the graphicOverlay;

### DrawGraphic.java;

```
public class DrawGraphic extends View {

    Paint borderPaint, textPaint;
    Rect rect;
    String text;

    ImageProxy imageProxy;
    PreviewView previewView;


    public DrawGraphic(Context context, Rect rect, String text, ImageProxy imageProxy, PreviewView previewView) {
        super(context);
        this.rect = rect;
        this.text = text;

        borderPaint = new Paint();
        borderPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(10f);
        borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setStrokeWidth(50f);
        textPaint.setTextSize(32f);
        textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.setMatrix(getMappingMatrix(imageProxy, previewView));
        canvas.concat(getMappingMatrix(imageProxy, previewView));
        canvas.drawText(text, rect.centerX(), rect.centerY(), textPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(rect.left, rect.bottom, rect.right, rect.top, borderPaint);

        ImageProxy imageProxy;
        PreviewView previewView;
    }

    Matrix getMappingMatrix(ImageProxy imageProxy, PreviewView previewView) {
        Rect cropRect = imageProxy.getCropRect();
        int rotationDegrees = imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        float[] source = {
                cropRect.left,
                cropRect.top,
                cropRect.right,
                cropRect.top,
                cropRect.right,
                cropRect.bottom,
                cropRect.left,
                cropRect.bottom
        };

        float[] destination = {
                0f,
                0f,
                previewView.getWidth(),
                0f,
                previewView.getWidth(),
                previewView.getHeight(),
                0f,
                previewView.getHeight()
        };

        int vertexSize = 2;

        int shiftOffset = rotationDegrees / 90 * vertexSize;
        float[] tempArray = destination.clone();
        for (int toIndex = 0; toIndex < source.length; toIndex++) {
            int fromIndex = (toIndex + shiftOffset) % source.length;
            destination[toIndex] = tempArray[fromIndex];
        }
        matrix.setPolyToPoly(source, 0, destination, 0, 4);
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1;

    private static final String PERMISSION_CAMERA = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;

    public static final Size DESIRED_PREVIEW_SIZE = new Size(640, 480);

    private PreviewView previewView;

    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);

        if (hasPermission()) {
            // Start CameraX
            startCamera();
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    private void startCamera() {
        ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            // Camera provider is now guaranteed to be available
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();

                // Set up the view finder use case to display camera preview
                Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();

                // Choose the camera by requiring a lens facing
                CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                        .build();

                // Image Analysis
                ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
                        new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                                .setTargetResolution(DESIRED_PREVIEW_SIZE)
                                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                                .build();

                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), imageProxy -> {
                    // Define rotation Degrees of the imageProxy
                    int rotationDegrees = imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees();
                    Log.v("ImageAnalysis_degrees", String.valueOf(rotationDegrees));

                    @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError") Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
                    if (mediaImage != null) {
                        InputImage image =
                                InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
                        //Pass image to an ML Kit Vision API
                        //...

                        LocalModel localModel =
                                new LocalModel.Builder()
                                        .setAssetFilePath("mobilenet_v1_0.75_192_quantized_1_metadata_1.tflite")
                                        .build();

                        CustomObjectDetectorOptions customObjectDetectorOptions =
                                new CustomObjectDetectorOptions.Builder(localModel)
                                        .setDetectorMode(CustomObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
                                        .enableClassification()
                                        .setClassificationConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
                                        .setMaxPerObjectLabelCount(3)
                                        .build();

                        ObjectDetector objectDetector =
                                ObjectDetection.getClient(customObjectDetectorOptions);

                        objectDetector.process(image)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(detectedObjects -> {
                                    getObjectResults(detectedObjects);
                                    Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess" + detectedObjects.size());
                                    for (DetectedObject detectedObject : detectedObjects) {
                                        Rect boundingBox = detectedObject.getBoundingBox();

                                        Integer trackingId = detectedObject.getTrackingId();
                                        for (DetectedObject.Label label : detectedObject.getLabels()) {
                                            String text = label.getText();
                                            int index = label.getIndex();
                                            float confidence = label.getConfidence();
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage()))
                                .addOnCompleteListener(result -> imageProxy.close());
                    }

                });

                // Connect the preview use case to the previewView
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(
                        previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

                // Attach use cases to the camera with the same lifecycle owner
                if (cameraProvider != null) {
                    Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                            this,
                            cameraSelector,
                            imageAnalysis,
                            preview);
                }

            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }

    private void getObjectResults(List<DetectedObject> detectedObjects) {
        for (DetectedObject object : detectedObjects) {
            if (binding.parentlayout.getChildCount() > 1) {
                binding.parentlayout.removeViewAt(1);
            }
            Rect rect = object.getBoundingBox();
            String text = "Undefined";
            if (object.getLabels().size() != 0) {
                text = object.getLabels().get(0).getText();
            }

            DrawGraphic drawGraphic = new DrawGraphic(this, rect, text);
            binding.parentlayout.addView(drawGraphic);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return checkSelfPermission(PERMISSION_CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(PERMISSION_CAMERA)) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Camera permission is required for this demo",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
            requestPermissions(new String[]{PERMISSION_CAMERA}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            final int requestCode, final String[] permissions, final int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted(grantResults)) {
                // Start CameraX
                startCamera();
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean allPermissionsGranted(final int[] grantResults) {
        for (int result : grantResults) {
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This all leads to my question on why the boundingBox is slightly "off". Any further information required to supplement this question will be provided upon request.

Comment: Probably you have created a scaled Bitmap let's say 300x300 and then you fed your network with that. Your network outputs a RectF with 4 points based on that (300x300). The thing here is to place these 4 points to a streched screen. One way to do it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62373305/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-the-screen-using-coordinates-with-texture-view/62373555#62373555 and the other to use a Matrix  with postScale and postTranslate like

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/env/ImageUtils.java#L168 in the original Object detection project.

Comment: Actually I have not used a scaled Bitmap, in my MainActivity.java, I have used a `media.Image` which is being streamed straight from my device camera. What would be the solution in this case?

Comment: You have to build this project https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android and see how you can use getTransformationMatrix . Unfortunately is not straightforward. You can also see here where Sayan uses directly the media.Image from CameraX instead of bitmap https://github.com/sayannath/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android . This project is on its way to be merged to the original tensorflow lite repo

Answer (score 1):

As stated in in the model description;

> Image data: ByteBuffer sized 192 x 192 x 3 x PIXEL_DEPTH, where PIXEL_DEPTH is 4 for float model, and 1 for quantized model.

Make sure your `media.Image` has same resolution. if you are giving a different image data this could result in wrong bounding box and detections. this might very well be reason why it is detected as spatula in the first place.
You can set your `ImageAnalysis` config to send you images with this resolution or you will have to resize the image before giving it as an input to your model.

And remember, the output bounding box will be according to 192 x 192 image. Now you will need to translate this coordinates to your preview view's coordinates. For that, there are a lot of solutions but you can use [this](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/transform-output#coordinates).

Comment: I had also built this same application using just [Google ML's base model](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/android) without TensorFlow that ended up having the same issue, which leads me to wonder whether the issue mainly resides in the resolution of the image that is being provided to the model.

Comment: Also, I should add that I have updated my OP with my `MainActivity.java` class with the code that you had provided. My only question would be where I would be calling the `getMappingMatrix` method? Seeing as though running the code as it is right now would only lead to the same predicament I'm in right now.

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but I found some APIs by Google search. Maybe you can give them a try by updating the onDraw logic in DrawGraphic.java to use the Matrix.    https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#setMatrix(android.graphics.Matrix).   or https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#concat(android.graphics.Matrix)

Comment: There is also another solution in the mlkit demo app without calculating the matrix. You can follow the code here https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/3eb63ccc5a42315e87a9e40fd9371d1c2c837cc5/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/objectdetector/ObjectGraphic.java#L102-L111 and dig into it.

Comment: @Steven, with the first two API's that you had found, you had stated that maybe updating the onDraw logic would help. Would you be able to expand on that slightly? I've attempted to replace the `onDraw` method with `setMatrix` and replace the former's content with the latter to no avail. I'm sure that's not what you had intended?

Comment: @Steven, with your second solution tied to the MLkit demo github, I have had some problems with attempting to implement the variables `translateX` & `translateY`. A quick Google search has led me to see that these two are tied to the JavaFX library. Is there any workaround for this? Once again, I thank you greatly for your help.

Comment: For using your getMappingMatrix method, try calling canvas.setMatrix/concat(getMappingMatrix(imageProxy, previewView)); right below super.onDraw(canvas);
You will need to pass imageProxy and previewView to DrawGraphic first to use them here.

Comment: @Steven, By pass, do you mean pass `imageProxy` and `previewView` as parameters for DrawGraphic? Because even upon doing so, I'm unable to call `getMappingMatrix` within the brackets for both `canvas.SetMatrix();` and `canvas.concat();`.

Comment: @Steven, this is how my passing of the interface and class looks like in DrawGraphic; `public DrawGraphic(Context context, Rect rect, String text, ImageProxy imageProxy, PreviewView previewView)`

Comment: If you store the imageProxy and previewView as class member variables of the DrawGraphic class when you got them in the constructor, then you can use them to call the getMappingMatrix method in the onDraw method.

Comment: If you are relatively new to this and feel a bit lost while debugging it, I would suggest instead of trying to write those code fully by yourself, try to understand the code in a sample app and then modify the sample app to achieve your goal.   Those "sample app" could either be one from the mlkit github repo https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android or some Google code labs: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/mlkit-android-odt#0

Comment: @Steven, for your convenience, I have updated my `DrawGraphic` class to display my situation thus far. I have stored `imageProxy` and  `previewView` as class member variables of the DrawGraphic class and stored them in the constructor. However, both `setMatrix` and `concat` are looking for a `Matrix matrix` input within the brackets. Also, I'm still unable to call the `getMappingMatrix` method in the onDraw method.

Comment: @Steven, I understand. It's just that with this being the final hurdle to my problems, I'm fairly bent on attempting to resolve it.

Comment: To clarify it again, I'm not sure if this approach will work. I just tried to follow your existing code and provide some tips to finish it.  The best way I would suggest is still to refer to a Code lab and learn related concepts then do it.   Given that, for your current code, to call the getMappingMatrix in onDraw, you would need to move the method declaration from the MainActivity file to the DrawGraphic file.   You also need to store the imageProxy and previewView as local variables in order to use them later in onDraw. The Matrix you are looking for is the return value of getMappingMatrix

Comment: @Steven Good news, I moved the entire getMappingMatrix method to the DrawGraphic file. From there, I was able to put imageProxy and previewView into the brackets for both `concat` and `setMatrix`. There seemed to be no errors present. However, upon running the application, I have been faced with a NullPointerException, which stated that `Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.graphics.Rect androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy.getCropRect()' on a null object reference`. This leads me to wonder whether I placed the two variables in the correct place. I updated my OP code with my new situation

Comment: @Steven Also, I completely understand that you're not entirely sure. I must let you know that all your help will not go unforgotten. I truly do appreciate all the progress you have been able to provide for me. I have been working on resolving this issue from a different perspective with [this question that I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69210990/how-to-find-the-input-output-image-resolution)

Comment: The reason why you got NullPointerException is because you didn't initialize them. You should pass imageProxy and previewView as param of the constructor of DrawGraphic and initialize the two local variables with them.       Please note, you need to pass these two values through the entire flow in MainActivity.java as well, otherwise, you may just get NullPointer at a different place.

Comment: @Steven Alright, so I have passed imageProxy and previewView as params of the constructor of DrawGraphic. However, would I be initializing the two local variables within DrawGraphic or OnDraw? Upon doing either of the two options, they both seem to not use the variable at all. In my updated example of my DrawGraphic class, I have initialized the variables within the OnDraw method.

Comment: @Steven Also, a bit of a secondary question; when you state that the two values must be passed through the entire flow in MainActivity.java, do you mean passing them into the constructor of the methods that use the values?

Comment: Hi RunMildew, I still see "DrawGraphic drawGraphic = new DrawGraphic(this, rect, text);" in your MainActivity, where you don't pass the preview and imageProxy into the constructor.  Also, in the DrawGraphic's constructor, you should assign them to the class member variables instead of ignoring them.

Comment: Sorry, I feel it would be hard for me to help you on this further. There is probably some missing knowledge in Android/Java.   If you have some friends who are familiar with Java or Android that could help you do some in-person side-by-side debug, I believe it would be more productive.    If not, taking some Android or Java online courses to set a more solid knowledge foundation could be helpful as well.